# Evaluate the integral $\int \frac{x}{(x^2+1)^2}dx$

Tags: integration

I am trying to follow an example from my textbook, mainly the u-substitution portion of this problem. Where I circled in red is the step where I get lost. Where did the $+1$ come from and why did the $u^2$ in the numerator disappear?

[image]

Comment: $1={u^2-4\over u^2-4}$ is all he's doing

Comment: I don't get the connexion between your question and the title...

Comment: He divided $u^2$ by $u^2-4$ by "long division". This is the first operation to do when the degree of the numerator of the integrand is greater than or equal to the degree of the denominator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\frac{u^2}{u^2 - 4} = \frac{(u^2 - 4) + 4}{u^2 - 4} = \frac{u^2 - 4}{u^2 - 4} + \frac4{u^2 - 4} = 1 + \frac4{u^2 - 4}$$

**Edit**: I am not sure how the integral in the title is related, but note that the derivative of $x^2 + 1$ is $2x$, which matches the numerator up to a constant factor. Thus the substitution $u = x^2 + 1$ transforms
$$ \int \frac{x}{(x^2+1)^2}\,dx $$
into
$$ \int \frac{1}{2u^2}\,du \,, $$
which you probably know how to solve.